# Decay function with accelerated decay

Tags: functions

I need to design a function with an specific shape. I cannot come up with some equation that fits the kind of function that I am looking for.

My requirements are:

1. The function is defined from 0 to N, where N is a natural number (it is a sample).after N, the signal returns 0.
2. the signal has a plateau or maximum where the signal starts. After some time, the amplitude decays rapidly until it touches the bottom (zero).
3. we can control the speed of decay by a coefficient k, that allows the function to be reduced more or less rapidly.

Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssNdr.png) of something similar but I am looking for a mirrored version:

What kind of function could fit these features?

Thanks!

Comment: Try $0.125-h(x)$. In general try manipulating [the sigmoid function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). It doesn't get to exactly zero though.

Comment: Great! thank you very much for your quick response. that is exactly what I am looking for. I modified the sigmoid function a little bit and it fits what I am looking for. I will set it manually to zero after it decays below the curve.

Comment: You could also try $\exp\left(k-\frac{k}{1-\left(\frac{x}{N}\right)^2}\right)$, which smoothly approaches $0$ as $x\to N^-$. Such a function would look like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function#/media/File:Mollifier_Illustration.svg).

Comment: that would also work! thanks. I will test it out